# missing UIToolBar in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm adding UIToolBar to my UITextField using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.email.delegate = self;
    self.password.delegate = self;

    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

    UIBarButtonItem* previous = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Anterior" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(move:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* next = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Próximo" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(move:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace) target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem* ok = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(ok:)];

    [toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:previous, next, space, ok, nil]];

    [toolbar setTranslucent:YES];
    [toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [(UITextField*)view setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
        }
    }

}
```

Now I'm adding a UIScrollView to my UIViewController and my UIToolBar doesn't show anymore. What am I missing? I think I'm adding the toolbar to the view and not to the scrollview, and because the scrollview is above the view, I can't see the toolbar. How can I fix it? I need to add to scroll view to move the content behind the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you have added a UIScrollView to your UIViewController.  I assume that means that the `self.email` and `self.password` are now subviews of this scroll view and not subviews of your main UIViewController's `view`.  So the code that iterates over the subviews of the `view` property will not find your UITextFields.

So your code:

```
for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) {
```

should look something like (I assume that the scrollView is a property):

```
for (UIView* view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
```

An alternative method to dealing with this is to use your UITextFieldDelegate methods to add the `inputAccessoryView` property in response to beginning editing.  So for example,

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
}
```